# cauchy product for general case

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

How to multiply this series:
$$(\sum_{t=-\infty}^{\infty}a_{t})(\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}b_{k})$$

Comment: Any answers to this question will depend on knowing something about the rates of convergence of your series. What do you know? 

Comment: this series are absolute convergence

Comment: Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s%5ftheorem#Corollary and replace the integrals by sums. Sums are indeed integrals with respect to counting measures, so this use of Fubini's theorem is completely kosher. Though of course, more elementary proofs can be given. (That wikipedia page needs some rewriting, though.)

Comment: I don't think that's the right kind of question for MO...

Comment: @Harald:  Sums are not *always* the same as integrals with counting measure: take any sum which converges nonabsolutely as an example.  For instance define $f(n) := (-1)^nn^{-1}$ for $n\in\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$.  The integral does not exist but the sum converges; this is remark 3.46 in baby rudin.

Comment: Right, but absolutely convergent sums have none of these subtleties.

Comment: -1, not just because of the level of the mathematics, but for vagueness (by which I mean: beyond signalling that the person asking was stuck, it didn't indicate IMHO what the person was stuck *on*)

Comment: sorry, was stupid question

Comment: can't delete it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a problem to multiply the series: the product is $\sum_{(t,k)\in\mathbb Z^2} a_tb_k$. The question is how to sum the double series that we have.

For series with nonnegative terms summation is not a problem either: we take the supremum of all finite sums. And since any finite sum is contained in a sufficiently large square, it follows that $\sum_{(t,k)\in\mathbb Z^2} |a_tb_k|$ is finite whenever $\sum_{t\in\mathbb Z} |a_t|$ and $\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z} |b_k|$ are.

In general, $\sum_{(t,k)\in\mathbb Z^2} a_tb_k=S$ if for any $\epsilon>0$ there is a finite subset $A\subset \mathbb Z^2$ such that $|\sum_{(t,k)\in B}a_tb_k - S|<\epsilon$ whenever $B$ is finite and $B\supset A$. Now if both given series converge absolutely, then the contribution from outside of a large square is small, and it follows that $S$ is the product of two sums.